# Why this syntax Object[key] show error in typescript ? how should I read properties from an object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I would like to create  one request map , that would some like one api request url config, then I could easy like send out a request just like ,sendRequest(name,body).
but this is some syntax error in typescript? it very strange

```
class HttpRequest {
baseURL = "http://localhost:8080" // get this by env later
requestMap = {
    "city":{
        method:"GET",
        url: this.baseURL+"/area/city" ,
    }

}

getRequest(requestName: String, body: object | null, params:null|object) {
   return axios({
        method:this.requestMap[String(requestName)]["method"],
        url: this.requestMap[requestName]["url"] ,
        params: params? params: null,
        data:body? body:null
    })
}
```

Comment: Where is the syntax error? Did you meant a type error? If this is the case it makes sense, since "city" is a string literal and `String(requestName)` is a string (not literal)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes,should be the String(requestName),  Thomaz's answer is rigth, thx for  help

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are getting this error: `Type 'String' cannot be used as an index type`, right?

You are getting this error because Typescript forces you to use a valid type for indexing an object, `requestMap` has only one property, called 'city', when you try to do `this.requestMap[String(requestName)]["method"]`, Typescript is telling you that String cannot index requestMap, and it is totally right about it, the method only exist in the `city` property.

To fix it, you can do any of those things:

Or changing the type of the requestName param to 'city':

```
 class HttpRequest {
  baseURL = "http://localhost:8080"; // get this by env later
  requestMap = {
    city: {
      method: "GET",
      url: this.baseURL + "/area/city",
    },
  };

  getRequest(requestName: 'city', body: object | null, params: null | object) {
    return axios({
      method: this.requestMap[requestName]["method"],
      url: this.requestMap[requestName]["url"],
      params: params ? params : null,
      data: body ? body : null,
    });
  }
}
```

Or, if you want some flexibily, you can create a type with all possible properties of the `requestMap`, somethings like this (when you know exacly what properties the object can have):

```
type RequestProps = "city" | "country";
type RequestPropsType = {
  method: string;
  url: string;
};

class HttpRequest {
  baseURL = "http://localhost:8080"; // get this by env later
  requestMap: Record<RequestProps, RequestPropsType> = {
    city: {
      method: "GET",
      url: this.baseURL + "/area/city",
    },
    country: {
      method: "GET",
      url: this.baseURL + "/area/country",
    },
  };

  getRequest(
    requestName: RequestProps,
    body: object | null,
    params: null | object
  ) {
    return axios({
      method: this.requestMap[requestName]["method"],
      url: this.requestMap[requestName]["url"],
      params: params ? params : null,
      data: body ? body : null,
    });
  }
}
```

But if you want full flexibity, making the requestMap be indexed by any string, you can change the String to string, but in this case, is not guaranteed the property will exist, so you should use the optional chaining operator [(available since typescript v3.7)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html) to avoid accessing functions of undefined:

```
class HttpRequest {
  baseURL = "http://localhost:8080"; // get this by env later
  requestMap = {
    city: {
      method: "GET",
      url: this.baseURL + "/area/city",
    },
  };

  getRequest(
    requestName: string,
    body: object | null,
    params: null | object
  ) {
    return axios({
      method: this.requestMap[requestName]?.["method"],
      url: this.requestMap[requestName]?.["url"],
      params: params ? params : null,
      data: body ? body : null,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarify. it helps me so much